# Удалить/запретить больше одного пробела между строками в инпуте

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Есть вот такое решение:

```
$(document).on('input', '[type="text"]', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""));
});
```

Как сделать чтобы между строками разрешался лишь один пробел?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант убирать пробелы после потери фокуса на инпуте

```
$(document).on("blur", '[type="text"]', function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ {2,}/g, " ").trim());
});
```